# Displaying data from h2 database in a list

Tags: spring

I'm trying to get a list of bids from the database by THE job id(which is a foreign key) but can't seem to figure out why im getting the below error. I have tired to look it up but can't get many questions that explain how to fix it.

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<ie.test.entities.Bid>] for value '[1]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type
```

Code:
controller:

```
@GetMapping("/jobs/{id}") 
public String showJobsy(@PathVariable(name="id") int id, Model model)
{
    List<Bid> bids = bidService.findBidsWithJobId(id);
    if (bids== null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("id", id);
        return "notfounderror";
    }
    model.addAttribute("bids", bids);

    return "bids";
```

entity:

```
@Entity
public class Job {

    @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobid",nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    public Job(String jobName, String description, LocalDateTime timestamp,  User User) {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.description = description;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.user = User;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int jobId;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String jobName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

}
```

BidDAO:

```
 @Query("SELECT c.id  FROM Bid c where c.job.id = :id") 
     List <Bid> findBidsWithJobId(int id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is not correct, you want to get `List<Bid>` but you are selecting ids. It should be:
`SELECT c FROM Bid c where c.job.id = :id`